# Set Form.Text at designer time to a non-constant string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, titlebar

Instead of set the [`form.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on VS property grid, I set the proper name in the application's assembly information so that everywhere I use the application's name or version I need to change in one place.

usually set the [`form.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this in the `Form1_Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName;
}
```

so that I only see the application name as I set in the assembly information only at run-time, at designer time I have "form1" so to change this I decided to move the line:

```
this.Text = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName;
```

To `InitializeComponent()` method, it worked, sort of. The title change but to this:

[image]

Is there any way to workaround this and get the proper name as I set in the assembly information rather than this Microsoft one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you see during design-time is host under another environment than your actual solution. Hence why you are seeing this behavior.

If you really want to view it during design-time, you should store the product name in a resource files or in the `App.config` as @Aniket pointed out.

Comment: Thanks. I give up this because whatever changes happen at GUI designer the code is generated again and my hjand-edited code go away. So makes no sense use it

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```

should contain the name of the application as set from the Assembly Name field under Project --> Properties.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean, but you can put things in your `App.config` settings file like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FormTitle" value="Your Title"/>
</appSettings>
```

And then read back into the application like:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormTitle"]
```

Or a ".resx" resource file